# Calculating dNBR for Image Collection in GEE

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, loop, for-loop, natural-disaster

I'm trying to calculate the differenced normalized burn ratio (DNBR) values for a Landsat image collection in Google Earth Engine for detect fire date and measure burned area using the following code; however, I keep getting the following error message:

`Line 41:collection.toList(...).get(...).get is not a function`

This error occurs on the line that calculates dnbr_list using a loop. I've tried using `collection.aggregate_array()` to retrieve a server-side list instead of `collection.toList()`, but it doesn't seem to fix the issue.

What could be causing this error, and how can I fix it?

Here is my code:

```
// Define the time range
var start_date = '2020-03-01';
var end_date = '2020-10-31';

// Define the geometry of the region we want to analyze
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([26.0, 39.0, 27.5, 40.5]);

// Load the image collection
var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterDate(start_date, end_date)
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .sort('system:time_start');

// Print the number of images in the collection
var count = collection.size();
print('Number of images: ', count);

// Define a function to calculate NBR values
function calculateNBR(image) {
  var nir = image.select('B5');
  var swir2 = image.select('B7');
  var nbr = nir.subtract(swir2).divide(nir.add(swir2));
  return nbr;
}

// Calculate DNBR values using a loop
var dnbr_list = [];
var image_list = collection.aggregate_array('system:id').map(function(id) {return ee.Image(id)});
for (var i = 0; i < count.getInfo() - 1; i++) {
  var nbr_pre = calculateNBR(ee.Image(image_list.get(i)));
  var nbr_post = calculateNBR(ee.Image(image_list.get(i+1)));
  var dnbr = nbr_pre.subtract(nbr_post).divide(nbr_pre.add(nbr_post));
  dnbr_list.push(dnbr);
}

// Calculate burned areas
var burned_area_list = [];
collection.iterate(function(image, info) {
  var index = ee.Number(info);
  var date_start = ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start'));
  var date_end = ee.Date(collection.toList(1, index.add(1)).get(0).get('system:time_start'));
  var date_range = date_start.format('yyyy-MM-dd').cat('-').cat(date_end.format('yyyy-MM-dd'));
  var dnbr_pre = calculateNBR(ee.Image(collection.toList(1, index).get(0)));
  var dnbr_post = calculateNBR(image);
  var dnbr = dnbr_pre.subtract(dnbr_post).divide(dnbr_pre.add(dnbr_post));
  var burned_pixels = dnbr.gt(0.2).selfMask().connectedPixelCount(30, true);
  var burned_area = ee.Number(burned_pixels).multiply(30*30).divide(10000);
  if (burned_pixels.gt(10)) { // Ignore areas with less than 10 pixels
    burned_area_list.push(ee.Feature(null, {
      'system:time_start': date_start,
      'date_range': date_range,
      'burned_area': burned_area
    }));
  }
  return index.add(1);
}, 0);

// Create a feature table and export it as a CSV file
var table = ee.FeatureCollection(burned_area_list);
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: table,
  description: 'burned_areas',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```

Comment: You deleted a question related to a "GEE loop" on Turkey area. By the way, I had an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the actual error is a missing cast to `ee.Image()` in between the `get()` calls. This:

```
var date_end = ee.Date(collection.toList(1, index.add(1)).get(0).get('system:time_start'));
```

should be

```
var date_end = ee.Date(ee.Image(collection.toList(1, index.add(1)).get(0)).get('system:time_start'));
```

As for the algorithm itself, you're mixing server-side looping with a client-side `if` and `Array.push()`. This will not work. Read up [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/client_server).

But even if you fix this, I don't think this algorithm will do what you want. You are calculating dNBR for the images in the collection, pairwise. Since your region covers more than one path/row, you will have pairs of images that doesn't overlap, leading to masked dNBR and causing you to miss actual changes in the NBR. To come up with a solution for this is a bit tricky, if you need a complete list of areas for all possible date combinations.

Maybe something like the below can work? No guarantee that it's completely correct - make sure to double check it. It runs at 300m scale. I didn't wait for it to complete at 30m scale. The print statement will probably fail at that scale, but the export hopefully works.

```
var startDate = ee.Date('2020-03-01')
var endDate = ee.Date('2020-11-01') // Exclusive
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Rectangle([26.0, 39.0, 27.5, 40.5])
var dNbrThreshold = 0.2

var collection = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
  .filterDate(startDate, endDate)
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .select(['SR_B7', 'SR_B5', 'QA_PIXEL'])
  .map(toNbr)

var dates = collection
  .aggregate_array('system:time_start')
  .distinct()
  
var nbrCollection = ee.ImageCollection(
  dates.map(toDailyNbr)
)
var dNbrCollection = nbrCollection.map(toDNbr)
var areas = dNbrCollection.map(toAreas).flatten()

print(areas)
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: areas,
  description: 'burned_areas',
  selectors: ['preDate', 'postDate', 'area']
});


function toAreas(dNbr) {
  var connectedPixels = dNbr.select('postDate')
    .multiply(1000).round().int32() // Hack fractional year to int to run connectedPixelCount()
    .connectedPixelCount(30)
  var connectedArea = connectedPixels
    .multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea())
    .divide(10000)
  var groups = ee.List(
    ee.Image.pixelArea()
      .addBands(dNbr.select('postDate'))
      .updateMask(connectedArea.gt(0.9))
      .reduceRegion({
        reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().group(1, 'postDate'), 
        geometry: geometry, 
        scale: 30,
        maxPixels: 1e13, 
        tileScale: 16
      }).get('groups')
  )
  
  var preDate = dNbr.getString('preDate')
  return ee.FeatureCollection(groups.map(function (group) {
    group = ee.Dictionary(group)
    var fractionalYear = group.getNumber('postDate')
    var year = fractionalYear.floor()
    var fraction = fractionalYear.subtract(year)
    var postDate = ee.Date
      .fromYMD(year, 1, 1)
      .advance(fraction, 'year')
      .format('yyyy-MM-dd')
    var area = group.getNumber('sum').divide(10000).round()
    return ee.Feature(null, {
      preDate: preDate,
      postDate: postDate,
      area: area
    })
  }))
}


function toDNbr(preNbr) {
  var postNbr = nbrCollection
    .filterDate(preNbr.date().advance(1, 'day'), endDate)
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull())
    .rename(['nbr', 'date'])
    .addBands(ee.Image([
      ee.Image().rename('nbr'),
      ee.Image().rename('date')
    ])).select(['nbr', 'date']) // Ensure we always have bands
    .float()
  var dNbr = ee.Image()
    .expression('pre - post', {
        pre: preNbr.select('nbr'),
        post: postNbr.select('nbr'),
    })
    .rename('dNbr')
  return dNbr
    .addBands(postNbr.select(['date'], ['postDate']))
    .updateMask(dNbr.mask().and(dNbr.gt(dNbrThreshold)))
    .set('preDate', preNbr.date().format('yyyy-MM-dd'))
}  


function toDailyNbr(millis) {
  var date = ee.Date(ee.Number(millis))
  var nbr = collection
    .filterDate(date.getRange('day'))
    .median()
    .addBands(ee.Image().rename('nbr')).select('nbr') // Ensure we always have an nbr band
    .float()
  var fractionalYear = ee.Image(date.get('year').add(date.getFraction('year')))
    .float()
    .updateMask(nbr.mask())
    .rename('date')
  return nbr
    .addBands(fractionalYear)
    .set('system:time_start', date.millis())
}
   
    
function toNbr(image) {
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL')
  var clear = bitwiseExtract(qa, 6)
  var date = ee.Date.fromYMD(
    image.date().get('year'),
    image.date().get('month'),
    image.date().get('day')
  )
  return image
    .multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2) // Rescale to 0-1. Important for Collection 2
    .normalizedDifference(['SR_B7', 'SR_B5'])
    // .updateMask(clear)
    .rename('nbr')
    .set('date', date)
    .set('system:time_start', date.millis())
}


function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined)
    toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
  var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
  return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/7eb83547b4fefe5c436cb05fc799eebf